# Como debo realizar el consumo de un cliente soap desde nodejs?

Tags: nodejs, soap

Estoy implementando el consumo de un servicio soap en una aplicacion que tiene su back end en Nodejs, bajo una arquitectura REST, el codigo del consumo es el siguiente:

```
let url = 'http://...';//por seguridad no comparto esta información :(
                let args = {document: '16277466', document_type: 'CO1C', service: 7};
                let user = '...', password = '...';
                let auth = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(`${user}:${password}`).toString('base64');

                soap.createClient(url, {wsdl_headers: {Authorization: auth}}, function (err: any, client: any) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('Error al consumir el soap: ', err.message);
                    } else {
                        console.log('llegue aqui');
                        client.Verificador_verificador_de_derechos_pscd_verificarconvenio_recreacion_MT(args, (err: any, response: any) => {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log('Error al consumir el metodo del soap: ', err);
                            } else {
                                console.log('Respuesta: ', response);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Pero al momento de ejecutar en la consola me sale el siguiente error:

```
llegue aqui
Error al consumir el soap:  client.Verificador_verificador_de_derechos_pscd_verificarconvenio_recreacion_MT is not a function
```

Pero si realizo el consumo desde SOAPUI me genera la respuesta esperada

Este es el cuerpo del xml de la petición en el SOAPUI:

```
<soapenv:Body>
      <urn:Verificador_verificador_de_derechos_pscd_verificarconvenio_recreacion_MT>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <document>16277466</document>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <document_type>CO1C</document_type>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <service>7</service>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <application>?</application>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <IdSerialContacto>?</IdSerialContacto>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <IdSerialProximidad>?</IdSerialProximidad>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <attributes>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <name>?</name>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <value>?</value>
         </attributes>
      </urn:Verificador_verificador_de_derechos_pscd_verificarconvenio_recreacion_MT>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Cuando realizo un client.describe() antes de consumir el metodo del cliente, este contiene información, pero cuando consume el metodo y arroja error el cliente queda undefined o null.